# Remove redundant file names in gnuplot figure

Tags: gnuplot

I wrote a simple gnuplot shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
reset

set terminal png

set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "Prime and Probe #"

plot "file.dat" with points
```

[image: plot result]

Notice that there is an annoying "file.dat" on the upper right corner. How can I remove that?

gnuplot Version 4.6 patchlevel 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `title` parameter to change the key

```
plot "file.dat" title "my title"
```

or remove it for a single plot

```
plot "file.dat" notitle
```

or remove it for all plots with

```
unset key
```

Comment: ... and see `gnuplot <<<'help plot title'`

Comment: Even  `plot "file.dat" title ""`  removes the key (I didn't know of `notitle`, had used `gnuplot` for say 20 years...)

Comment: @gboffi Indeed. I thought two variants would be enough, but using an empty string can be quite useful when you need a conditional for switching the key on or off.